Ubuntu 22.04 agetty login problems
I am running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS on x86_64. It boots to a full graphical login.
I managed to find a vintage DEC VT320 terminal and hook it up using a USB to serial port adapter and a DEC specific MMJ to DB9 cable I bought from the DECromancer. My goal is to hook it up to the Linux box so I can run command line programs for a little retro fun. It doesn't need to be a console. Just a regular login prompt is plenty good.
First I plugged in the USB port and watched dmesg to find that it had been detected and given /dev/ttyUSB0. So far so good.
I set the terminal to 9600 bps, 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit. (This is the standard.) Then I ran minicom and set it to the same thing. I was able to type text on the terminal and see it on minicom and vice versa. So I am pretty sure that the terminal, cable, and serial port are working great.
The next step is to put a login prompt on it so a user on the VT320 can log in and run bash and other programs.
I found these guides:

https://www.rogerirwin.co.nz/linux-open-source/enabling-a-serial-port-console/


https://medium.com/@jobinjohn819/setting-up-autologin-on-virtual-serial-console-in-systemd-based-linux-systems-2ed46c6c0b11

They appear to be the best guides I can find on the matter.
I did this:
sudo -i
cd /lib/systemd/system
cp serial-getty@.service serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
nano serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service

Then use the editor to change:
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,57600,38400,9600 %I $TERM

to
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' 9600 %I $TERM

This was to force it to use 9600 bps and no other speed.
Then start the service with:
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service

The result:
# systemctl status serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
● serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service - Serial Getty on ttyUSB0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-08-30 18:35:30 EDT; 1h 33min ago
       Docs: man:agetty(8)
             man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
             http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
   Main PID: 9779 (agetty)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18901)
     Memory: 212.0K
        CPU: 5ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-serial\x2dgetty.slice/serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
             └─9779 /sbin/agetty -o "-p -- \\u" 9600 ttyUSB0 vt220

Aug 30 18:35:30 zbox systemd[1]: Started Serial Getty on ttyUSB0.

So far so good. Now looked at the VT320 and it displayed:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS zbox ttyUSB0

zbox login:

I can hit "enter" repeatedly and get more of the "zbox login:" prompts. I can type anything I want for the username and it echoes my characters back perfectly. Even the backspace works.
But as soon as I enter a name and press enter, it hangs. It doesn't matter if the user exists or doesn't. It doesn't ask for a password. It just hangs. Nothing I type on the terminal shows up. It's just stuck.
The service appears to be up still:
# systemctl status serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
● serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service - Serial Getty on ttyUSB0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-08-30 20:11:38 EDT; 2min 15s ago
       Docs: man:agetty(8)
             man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
             http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
   Main PID: 13842 (login)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18901)
     Memory: 812.0K
        CPU: 18ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-serial\x2dgetty.slice/serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
             └─13842 /bin/login -p -- "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

Aug 30 20:11:38 zbox systemd[1]: Started Serial Getty on ttyUSB0.

After waiting about a minute, the full login prompt appears again:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS zbox ttyUSB0

zbox login:

I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. It seems that the terminal and the serial connection are all solid. I can log in graphically. I can ssh in. But this isn't working.
Any ideas?

Update:
Tried turning off the service and running from the root command line:
systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
getty -L 9600 ttyUSB0 vt102

I get the same behavior. I get the login banner and login prompt. When I enter a username, it freezes. After a while, the getty command terminates. Don't know why.
Or
systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
agetty -L 9600 ttyUSB0 vt102

I don't get the banner, but I get the login prompt. Otherwise the same lockup behavior.

Update 2:
Found out through lsusb -t info about the USB to serial adapter:
Port 8: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=pl2303, 12M

So it must be the extremely common Prolific PL2303.
I also hooked the USB to serial device to a Raspberry Pi 4 I had lying around running the standard Raspbian. It detected the USB device just fine. As root I ran the "getty" command and it did the EXACT same thing. It gave me the login banner and login prompt. And it locked up in exactly the same way. Interesting. Is the USB port bad in some way? Yet with minicom it works great. Odd!
I generated the "strace" log and gave it to a trusted friend. While analyzing it, they pointed out that it is sending a "Login timed out." right before the process ends, but we never see it on the terminal. Also it doesn't ever seem to send the "Password:" prompt.
Stranger and stranger!

You can get lots of debug output with strace -t -x -f -v -s 999 -o /tmp/out agetty -L 9600 ttyUSB0 vt102. Look for ioctl calls and writes to the tty file descriptor. You can find that as the result of, say, open(..."/dev/ttyUSB0",...) = 4, where 4 is the fd used in later calls. The system calls may not be exactly "open" but "openat" and so on. The timestamp will show where the hang starts, so work back from there. A change in tty baud rate will be seen as ioctl(..., c_cflag=...). You can also try stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB0 during the pause.

Side note: you should be creating file serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service in directory /etc/systemd/system/. /lib is for the distributed files, /etc is for locally created files, and takes priority.

Is vt220 (which appears to be a hardwired systemd-getty-generator default) actually the correct terminfo entry for the device? Have you tried replacing $TERM with one of the *320* terminfo entries (vt320 or vt320-w etc.)?

Thanks for the replies. I gave the "stty" command a try and it showed that it stayed at 9600 baud the whole time, before, during, and after the fatal pause. As for the "strace", it's really big, but I went hunting around for the ioctl calls. I also used the old "tail -f" trick on the output file to find where I enter my username and hit enter. I can clearly see every letter get read and written, but from there, it's so much stuff I can't figure it out. Sorry.

I was using vt102 and I had the terminal in vt100 mode. I tried vt320 and put the terminal in vt300 mode (it doesn't have a vt320 in the menu) and had the same results. I don't think this is the issue.

I found the solution!
Suspecting a hardware fault, I did a longer search and found another USB-serial device around the house.
When I plugged it in, I got this from lsusb -t:
Port 8: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=pl2303, 12M

So it's the same chipset. Oh well. I tried it anyway.
And sure enough, it worked. It worked the first time. So the old USB-serial port has a hardware fault of some kind that is very hard to spot. I don't understand it to say any more than "hardware failure".
So I went back, put the terminal is VT300 mode (ID = 220). I used the "systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service" command as mentioned before.
The VT let me log in and I'm running screen and various programs. It's working great!
Later on I'll try to put it in true vt320 mode and up the speed from 9600 bps. But for now, I'm going to consider this a victory. :)

Update:
Works great at 19200 bps, which is the maximum speed of the terminal. Seems to work better in bash, nano, and other Unixy applications with the terminal set to vt220 in Linux (and the terminal set to vt300 8 bit mode in the vt itself) than setting Linux to vt320. I don't know why. the arrow keys don't seem to work right.
Talking to some friends, they suspect that the first "defective" USB-serial adapter may be a knockoff part that doesn't full conform to the part's specs. That is entirely possible. It would explain why it works so well in minicom. It was by far the more "low cost" of the two adapters. But I don't have the skills or tools to prove it. So for now, it remains a conjecture.
